# How to Auto-Populate Textboxes in C#?

Tags: c#

How do i Auto-populate a textbox based on input from 2 other text boxes?

For example :

Firstname : John

Lastname : Smith

Alias : JSmit   (Takes First Initial, and first 4 letters in lastname)

Nickname : JSmith  (Takes first initial, + Lastname )

How would i write this in C#? it's a Windows form in visual Studio 2013

I think for Nickname i can just use txtNickname.text = *Some wierd A^@#%@ Thing * + txtLastname.Text;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txtNickname.Text = txtFirstName.Text[0] + txtLastName.Text;
txtAlias.Text = txtFirstName.Text[0] + txtLastName.Text.Substring(0, 4);
```

You *may* need to add some trappings for the string lengths. :)

Comment: This works great. My only question is, how can i make the Textboxes display the alias and nickname as theyre being typed?

Comment: you may do something similar to what @Binkan Salaryman is suggesting. or you may use the text changed event of your txtFirstName and txtLastName text boxes. do you know how to use these? if not, i can comment it here for you

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to implement Data-Bindings in Windows Forms - you might take a look at [this Tutorial](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html). As an alternative you can do this easily with [WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29054/WPF-Data-Binding-Part)

Here is some sample WPF-style code for Windows Forms:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public string FirstName { get { return txtFirstName.Text; } set { txtFirstName.Text = value; } }
    public string LastName { get { return txtLastName.Text; } set { txtLastName.Text = value; } }
    public string NickName { get { return txtNickName.Text; } set { txtNickName.Text = value; } }

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        UpdateNickName();
        txtFirstName.TextChanged += (s, e) => FirePropertyChanged("FirstName");
        txtLastName.TextChanged += (s, e) => FirePropertyChanged("LastName");
        txtNickName.TextChanged += (s, e) => FirePropertyChanged("NickName");
        PropertyChanged += Form1_PropertyChanged;
    }

    void Form1_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        switch(e.PropertyName) {
            case "FirstName":
            case "LastName":
                UpdateNickName();
                break;
        }
    }

    void UpdateNickName() {
        if(FirstName.Length > 1 && LastName.Length > 4) {
            NickName = FirstName.Substring(0, 1) + "" + LastName.Substring(0, 4);
        } else {
            NickName = "";
        }
    }

    public void FirePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = "") {
        if(PropertyChanged != null) {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```